# Can I get the index of a python dictionary from its value?

Tags: python

```
dict = {
 a: [(21, ['one', 'two', 'three'])]
 b: [(21, ['four', 'five'])]}
```

I want to develop a function that returns a when I pass 'three' as an argument. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You can, but with your arrangement, it will be inefficient. You can creating a reverse-lookup dictionary making the values of your `dict` as keys, and their values are the original `dict`'s key.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Comment: What is your question actually ?

Comment: @Fuji: "
I want to develop a function that returns a when I pass 'three' as an argument. How can I achieve that?"

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have saved all the values in your `dict`, say:

```py
dict = {
 a: [(21, ['one', 'two', 'three'])]
 b: [(21, ['four', 'five'])]}
```

Then, to access the keys given the value, you would need to reverse their relationship (this will speed up the lookup in exchange for more memory):

```py
lookup = {}
for key in dict.keys():
    for value in dict[key][0][1]: #this is the list inside the tuple inside the list
        lookup[value] = key
```

So, when you are looking for the key of the required values, you can just go:

```py
print('out:', lookup['three'])
```

which will output:

```py
out: a
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via iterating over every item in the dictionary, however in large data sets it may be inefficient.

```
def get_key(data, query):
    for key, value in data.items():
        if query in value[0][1]:
            return key
    return 'Not Found'
```

You can then call your function with `get_key(dictonary, word)` and have a result returned even if your lookup fails to find a match.

```
# Note i changed the name of the dictionary to dicton, as dict shouldn't be used as a variable name
print(get_key(dicton, 'three'))
print(get_key(dicton, 'seven'))
print(get_key(dicton, 'four'))

#a
#Not Found
#b
```